# Prestashop 1.7.8 Specific Price - Smarty - retrieve day

Tags: prestashop, smarty

As they still haven't decided to put the time to work in the date-picker of discounts.

Wouldn't it be possible to take 1 day off the code that shows the end date of the promotion?

This code displays the end date of the promotion, but due to the time issue the promotion ends before the end of the day, so we have to add a day on the backoffice side. And the idea in this code was to remove the extra day to hit the date right, you know?

```
{l s='End promo: '}{$product->specificPrice.to|date_format:'%d-%m-%Y' . "-1 days"}
```

but not working... i have tried a lot of combinations and nothing.

I await your comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Please try {"$product->specificPrice.to -1 Days"|date_format:'%d-%m-%Y' }

Comment: Hello @Sachin thank you. I have tried, but not working. gives a error: Object of class PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductLazyArray could not be converted to string

Comment: Try this {strftime("+3 days",$product->specificPrice.to)|date_format:"Y-m-d"}

Comment: Hello @Sachin does not work to. Thank you for try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
{if $product.has_discount}{dateFormat date=$product.specific_prices.from} to {dateFormat date=$product.specific_prices.to|cat:' -1 day'|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'}{/if}
```

Hope this works for you guys to!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :

```
{l s='End promo: '}{"$product->specificPrice.to -1 Days"|date_format:'%d-%m-%Y'}
```

Comment: I have already given this suggestion in my first comment which did not work out for him.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed! anyway this is the correct working answer (assuming that the $product->specificPrice.to is a proper "Y-m-d H:i:s" string) ...  I just tested in a PS 1.7.8 template.

Comment: Hello user3256843 this is not working on my installation of prestashop: this is the error: FatalThrowableError
Object of class PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductLazyArray could not be converted to string

Comment: Hello @user3256843 this is not work and giving a error in my prestashop 1.7.8 :
 (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Object of class PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductLazyArray could not be converted to string

in 36472cd63fee1fc1376359ba8970b78eccb33fe4_2.file.product.tpl.php line 809
at Block_50087254562c566feddd1d9_19903904->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248

Comment: so I guess "$product->specificPrice.to" is not a string. What's printed in the TPL if you do a {$product->specificPrice.to|var_dump} ?

Comment: hello @user3256843, sorry for the delay on answering, i got error again when i put the var_dump.

Comment: @user3256843 i have found the solution, you can look above. thank you